# Magento custom theme configurable swatch not switching image

Tags: javascript, magento, colors

My magento custom theme is not switching images.
I`m seeing this error while hovering over the color:

```
Product.ConfigurableSwatches.onOptionOut    @   swatches-product.js:540
(anonymous function)    @   swatches-product.js:325
Object.extend.__method  @   prototype.js:391
responder   @   prototype.js:5598
```

My website [url](http://www.viaflexcalcados.com.br/sandalia-usaflex-em-couro-com-tiras-102964.html): http://www.viaflexcalcados.com.br/sandalia-usaflex-em-couro-com-tiras-102964.html

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js

**skin/frontend/novaworks/nova_bazien/js/app.js**

error in line no 1227. Change your code

```
        image.elevateZoom(settings);
    },
$j(".product-image-gallery").on("click", function(e) {
    var src = $j('.product-image img.visible').attr('src');
$j.fancybox(src);
});
    swapImage: function(targetImage) {
        targetImage = $j(targetImage);
```

To

```
   image.elevateZoom(settings);

   $j(".product-image-gallery").on("click", function(e) {
   var src = $j('.product-image img.visible').attr('src');
        $j.fancybox(src);
   });
},

swapImage: function(targetImage) {
    targetImage = $j(targetImage);
```